# a case to do other desired cases in a loop with input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script, shell-script

I want 4 case to do 1 and 2 (or any other cases)but can't figure out how...

when input is 4 I want this as output

1111111111111111111111111111

2222222222222222222222222222

executing 1 and 2 one after each other

FYI: I'm going to use this for more choices

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
  read  -p "$(echo ${LRED}Please choose: ${NC})" INPUT_STRING
  case $INPUT_STRING in
        
    1)  

        echo "1111111111111111111111111111"
        ;;
        
    2)
        echo "2222222222222222222222222222"
        ;;
    3)
        echo "333333333333333333333333333"
        ;;

    4) 
        
        ;;
    *)
    ;;
    
  esac
  done
```

Comment: The man page implies (but does not outright state) that you can't use case to do this - see https://ss64.com/bash/case.html "The first pattern that matches determines the command-list that is executed.". Use if...then statements instead.

Comment: Another alternative would be to call sets of functions and have 4 call the functions associated with 1 and 2.

Comment: Side note: you tagged [tag:bash] but the shebang is `/bin/sh`, but `read -p` is not portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract the common code as a function. Here the most straightforward way is to have two functions. Define them before the main loop:

```
first() {
   echo "1111111111111111111111111111"
}

second() {
   echo "2222222222222222222222222222"
}
```

And then the relevant fragment will be:

```
1)
    first
    ;;
2)
    second
    ;;
3)
    echo "333333333333333333333333333"
    ;;
4) 
    first; second
    ;;
```